# ShortCut on meta boxes

Tags: metabox

There any way to run a shortcut that is in a meta box?

I'm trying to execute the shortcut but does nothing, is that if the code comes from the wordpress editor does not have any problem

Comment: Shortcut or shortcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `do_shortcode()` on your meta box content: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the wordpress filters and when `do_shortcode` gets added to `the_content`. meta box content doesn't come from `the_content` therefore doesn't get filtered and no shortcode gets executed. You have to add the filter to your meta box content yourself.